# strip_tags() function blacklist rather than whitelist

Tags: php

I recently discovered the `strip_tags()` function which takes a string and a list of accepted html tags as parameters.

Lets say I wanted to get rid of images in a string here is an example:

```
$html = '<img src="example.png">';
$html = '<p><strong>This should be bold</strong></p>';
$html .= '<p>This is awesome</p>';
$html .= '<strong>This should be bold</strong>';

echo strip_tags($html,"<p>");
```

returns this:

```
<p>This should be bold</p>
<p>This is awesome</p>
This should be bold
```

consequently I gotten rid of my formatting via `<strong>` and perhaps `<em>` in the future.

I want a way to blacklist rather than whitelist something like:

```
echo blacklist_tags($html,"<img>");
```

returning:

```
<p><strong>This should be bold<strong></p>
<p>This is awesome</p>
<strong>This should be bold<strong>
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Blacklisting is the wrong approach here. Stick to the whitelist and add all items you want. Just because you **will** miss elements when blacklisting, for example <video>, <script>, etc.

Comment: I will miss elements? I only want `<img>` tags removed. I would have to add every tag to prevent removing tags accidentally `eg <p><em><strong><blockquote><ul><li>`.

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">document.write('<img src="…">');</script>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you only wish to remove the `<img>` tags, you can use `DOMDocument` instead of `strip_tags()`.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($your_html_string);

// Find all the <img> tags
$imgs = $dom->getElementsByTagName("img");

// And remove them
$imgs_remove = array();
foreach ($imgs as $img) {
  $imgs_remove[] = $img;
}

foreach ($imgs_remove as $i) {
  $i->parentNode->removeChild($i);
}
$output = $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: I wasn't aware that `removeChild()` would remove any descending element, in stead of only a direct child. Good to know. Edit: Or am I misinterpreting things?

Comment: @fireeyedboy yes, it is possible to remove any node, not necessarily a direct descendant

Comment: @fireeyedboy Acually I just tested and it doesn't work as I though. Instead, you have to remove from the `parentNode`. Changed above.

Answer (score 1):

You can only do this by writing a custom function. Strip_tags() is considered more secure though, because you might forget to blacklist some tags...

PS: Some example functions can be found in the comments on [php.net's strip_tags() page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)