# preg_replace returns 'array' in var_dump

Tags: php, html, arrays, preg-replace

SOLVED!! :-)

Thanks for comments everyone especially 'Valentin Rusk' I would never have spotted it otherwise.

Turns out it was my own stupid fault for trying to put a multidimensional array through preg_replace.

Solved by using:

```
$main_stripped = preg_replace($removetags_reg, '',$main_data[1][0]);
```

Left the question up for any unfortunate soul in the same position!

---

Ok first sorry for a such a simple question, I am the one that hides in the background reading and trying to solve my own problems but I give up with this one today is not my day.

Really simple (I hope),
I am trying to remove the contents between 2 HTML tags, the original content comes from a `file_get_contents`.

When using `var_dump` the `preg_replace` I am using for this chooses to output 2 strings just saying array.

I have tried outputting using indexes (ie `var_dump($main_stripped[1][0]);` etc) but it then just outputs the string saying `array`.

I have also tried using `echo $maindata;` but this just returns the string again 'array'.

```
$maindata = 'needed needed needed needed needed needed needed <figure> rubbish rubbish
<\figure> needed needed etc etc';  

// stripped 
$removetags_reg = '/<figure(.+?)<\/figure>/is';
$main_stripped = preg_replace($removetags_reg, '',$main_data);

echo '</br></br>Test Dump:</br></br>';

var_dump($main_stripped);
```

Please help restore my sanity, I didn't even know `var_dump` could output `array` I thought only echo did it if you put an array in by mistake?

Comment: Could you edit your question, and include the actual output you're getting from `var_dump()`?

Comment: where is `$main_data` defined?

Comment: Take a look at this answer if you want to remove specific html tags and their contents: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7072410/42139

Comment: Check the entering data. you have a problem with data that enters into preg_replace. The function return array in ONLY case, when array is passed as subject($main_data).