# Convert selected html tags into string

Tags: php, html

I am looking to convert **some** HTML tags into strings. I want to be able to provide an array of tags which are to be converted into strings.

The 3 tags I am looking at are: img, iframe and script which should all display as a string when found inside a string.

Example:

Array: `$tags = array("img");`
String: `This is a picture of my dog <img src="......">`

I have looked at `htmlentities`, `htmlspecialchars`, etc. but they all seem to be all or nothing solutions.

Can any one help?

Thanks

Comment: What is your input exactly ? You want to read an HTML file and change tags in it into simple string, or what ? Give a more detailed example please

Comment: @ClémentMalet I have a string which can contain HTML. I want to scan through this HTML and if any img, iframe or script tags appear I want to convert them into a string so they don't display. All other html tags should be left alone.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) function might help you.

Comment: How? This has not functionality to define which tags to convert as far as I can see?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do, but if you want to convert a tag to a string, htmlentities will do it.

Comment: $tags = array('<img src="">', '<iframe></iframe>', '<script></script>'); foreach($tags as $tag) { echo htmlentities($tag); }

Answer (score 1):

This is not working for non pair tags, but can be easily edited:

```
  function convert_to_entities($data,$tags) {
    foreach($tags as $tag) {
      while(strpos($data,"<$tag") !== false) {
        $reg = "@(.*)<$tag(.*)>(.*)</$tag>(.*)@";
        $data = preg_replace($reg,"$1&lt;$tag$2&gt;$3&lt;/$tag&gt;$4",$data);
      }
    }
    return $data;
  }
```

The first parameter is the string and second is array of tags.

Comment: This times out for me.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php):

> > strip_tags — Strip HTML and PHP tags from a string

I know you're actually looking for a blacklist ("explicitly filter out *these* tags") but maybe you should rethink and use a whitelist instead ;)

See this related question: [strip_tags() function blacklist rather than whitelist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072327/strip-tags-function-blacklist-rather-than-whitelist)