# How to use two preg_replace

Tags: php

Knowing that:

```
$str = $row_ultimos_posts['conteudo'];
```

I have this code:

```
echo preg_replace("/<iframe[^>]+\>/i", "",$str);
```

And I have this code:

```
preg_replace ("/<img(.+?)>/", "",$str);
```

How can I use both codes? How to merge it to work?

Comment: `preg_replace('/<(iframe|img)(.*?)>/', '', $str);` But [don't parse html with regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/418413).

Comment: It occurs to me that this will remove the opening iframe/img tag, but not the closing one. Just one more argument against parsing html with regular expressions.

Comment: Regex is probably the wrong approach here. [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072327/strip-tags-function-blacklist-rather-than-whitelist) (related)

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace("/<iframe[^>]+\>/i", "",preg_replace ("/<img(.+?)>/", "",$str));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can basically wrap them in a function like

```
function foo($str)
{

$str = preg_replace("/<iframe[^>]+\>/i", "",$str);
$str = preg_replace ("/<img(.+?)>/", "",$str);

return $str;

}
```